# Imprimir posição de uma matriz

Tags: c++

A intenção neste programa seria imprimir a posição `linha` e `coluna` em que se localiza o maior valor da dentro da matriz, alguém sabe me dizer por que no resultado está imprimindo `0x0` e se existe outro caminho mais eficaz? No meu teste é claro, o valor maior digitado não foi o primeiro.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int matriz[3][3],i,j,maior=0,i1,j1;

main(){
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("Digite um valor: ");
            scanf("%d",&maior);
            if(matriz[i][j]>maior){
                maior=matriz[i][j];
                i1=i;
                j1=j;
            }//fim if
        }//fim for j
    }//fim for i
    printf("%d x %d \n",i1,j1);
    system("pause");
}//fim do main
```

Comment: Sua matriz não é inicializada em lugar nenhum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude:

```
scanf("%d",&maior);
```

Para:

```
scanf("%d",&matriz[i][j]);
```

Você não está lendo o valor correto.